# Display mysql query results on a new page from links

Tags: php, mysql

I create a table and display entries from MySQL in a brief table report format. Each of the entries in the table have further properties that I would like to display on a separate page when I click on the link in their names.

```
<?php
        require_once 'includes/db.php';
        connect();

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM persons order by date_entered DESC LIMIT 5";
                    $response = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    if($response){
                    echo '<div id="frm"> <h2> Last 5 candidates entered </h2> <table align="left">
                    <tr>
                            <td align="left"><b>First Name</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Email</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Sex</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>City</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Phone Number</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Education</b></td>
                            <td align="left"><b>Salary</b></td>
                    </tr>';

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
                    echo '<tr>
                            <td align="left">' . '<a href="person.php">' . $row["first_name"] . " " .$row['last_name'] . '</a>' . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['sex'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['city'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['education'] . '</td>
                            <td align="left">' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                    } else {
                    echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
                    echo mysqli_error($con);
                    }
                    mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
```

This gives me a table report with links in the names:

[brief report with link in names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlva7.png)

My question is: if I click Mary Swanson in the table, what variables do I use in person.php so I can retrieve the MySQL data for that record?

Thanks.

Comment: It all depends does the row has a id column you can use?

Comment: Hi Geraldo,Yes, all rows have unique IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass this id trough the link as a GET variable and use it on the other side to query the database for that specific record like this:

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/db.php';
    connect();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM persons order by date_entered DESC LIMIT 5";
    $response = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    if($response){
        echo '<div id="frm"> <h2> Last 5 candidates entered </h2> <table align="left">
                        <tr>
                                <td align="left"><b>First Name</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Email</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Sex</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>City</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Phone Number</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Education</b></td>
                                <td align="left"><b>Salary</b></td>
                        </tr>';

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            echo '<tr>
                                <td align="left">' . '<a href="person.php?id=' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["first_name"] . " " .$row['last_name'] . '</a>' . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['email'] . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['sex'] . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['city'] . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['education'] . '</td>
                                <td align="left">' . $row['salary'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Then you can access the variable on the other side like this $_GET["id"])

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/db.php';
connect();

$query = "SELECT * FROM persons where id = " . $_GET["id"]);
$response = mysqli_query($con, $query)
```

After this you can print the values returned by the query as if where a multiple row select, but it will only come back with one row, you still need to do the while since what it returns is an array.

Comment: Thanks Geraldo, when i add the $row["person_id"] it also displays the id  in my brief report which I dont really want to. Any way to get the without displaying it?

Comment: Apologies Geraldo, I am being dumb. Your suggestion worked! Would you mind helping me with the $_GET syntax for the person.php, just to get me going. I am very new to php and struggling at times :S. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Sure no problem, Ill update the answer with instructions, give me a sec.

Comment: That's great! Thank you very much Geraldo. I really appreciate your help! I accepted your answer, is there anything else I need to do? Regards, Roberto.

Comment: All good my friend! hope everything goes all right with your project.